# I am getting error while using else function in Python

Tags: python

```
x = 30
y = 60

if (x>y):
    print("True")

    else:
        print("False")
```

Error

```
 File "<ipython-input-1-05aca812b623>", line 7
    else:
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: What editor are you using?

Comment: Python is sensitive to tabs, so align the else to lhe level of the if and print false at the same level of the print true.

Comment: Using Jupyter notebook

Answer (score 0):

The `else` needs to be vertically aligned with the `if`.

Answer (score 0):

I think Problem is  indentation
Try below.

```
x = 30 
y = 60

if (x>y):
    print("True")

else:
    print("False")
```

Answer (score 0):

This code runs fine.

```
x = 30 
y = 60

if (x>y): 
    print("True")

else:
    print("False")
```

indentation is very important in python. Make sure you indent your code properly.

Answer (score 0):

Indentation is important in python. Indent your code properly and it will work fine.

```
x = 30 
y = 60
if (x>y): 
    print("True")
else:
    print("False")
```